# fill second drop down based on firsts drop down value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

The tables in test.html are getting create dynamically on a button click add event.  The var i is further up in the script.

The html runs and and allows me to select a value from service selection (The selection in the first drop down should simply return a 0,1,2). The value of the selection is passed onto support/descriptions.php via a post, a mysql query is made and I hope to return the result array back to the selection called description.  I currently get no values on the alert of the array or vales back to the second selection, but I get no errors either. Do you see anything in the php file preventing the array from getting filled? What is the reason the div for the second drop down is not getting filled either?

The second alert returns a message with the following:

```
<option value="Array">Array</option>
<option value="Array">Array</option>
<option value="Array">Array</option>
<option value="Array">Array</option>
<option value="Array">Array</option>
```

test.html

```
$(document).on('change', '.service', function () {  
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
       $.post("support/descriptions.php", {
            id: $(this).val()           
        },
        function (data) {
    var response = (data).split(";", 2);
            alert(response[0]);
            alert(response[1]);
    $("#descript" + I).html(response[1]);
        });
        return false;
    });


<table>
        <th>Catagory</th>
        <th>Select Item</th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class ="service" name="service' + i + '" id="' + i + '">
                <option value="0">Select One</option>
                <option value="1">Hardscape</option>
                <option value="2">Plants</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="description' + i + '" id="' + i + '"><div id="descript' + i + '"></div></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

descriptions.php

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($id == 1){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Distinct description FROM hardscape");
    }
    if($id == 2){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Distinct description FROM plants");
    }

$options = '<option value="Select One">Select One</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $options .= '<option value="'. $row['description'] .'">'. $row['description'] .'</option>';
    }
echo $id .";".$options.";";
    ?>
```

UPDATE -

My issue with the array not getting populated is because I was using ";" as a parse.  I found that my data had ";" in them so for testing I changed

```
echo $id .";".$options.";";
```

to

```
echo $id ."~".$options."~";
```

I also change my div from the inside to the outside

```
<select name="description' + i + '" id="' + i + '"><div id="descript' + i + '"></div></select>
```

to

```
<div id="descript' + i + '"><select name="description' + i + '" id="' + i + '"></select></div>
```

Last but not least I had to change my php file to the following to rebuild the whole selection:

```
$options = '<select><option value="Select One">Select One</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $options .= '<option value="'. $row['description'] .'">'. $row['description'] .'</option>';
    }
    $options .='</select>';
echo $options;
```

Comment: Just use JSON, why build your own little parser?

Comment: Seriously, use JSON. Nope, this is not simpler! :)

Comment: I tried a JSON example first and could get it to return anything either.  The parser is just for testing....do not need to echo back any more than the array when done.

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is an array, to get the field `description` you have to get it from the array, `$row['description']`

```
$options .= '<option value="'. $row['description'] .'">'. $row['description'] .'</option>';
```

Comment: I appreciate your response back.  I originally had that, but didn't post it.

Comment: I was able to figure out why the array was not working.  It was the parse value of ; in echo $id .";".$options.";";